# Nagios Notification via Ubuntu notify-osd

Tags: notification, notify-osd, monitoring, network-monitoring, nagios3

I have been looking around for a nagios plugin that offers the ability to have alerts for my hosts and services that i monitor to come through to my ubuntu pc in the form of an onscreen notification.

I have some experience working with nagios and custom checks and notification methods, I dont how ever have any experience working with the ubuntu notify-osd package.

Any help or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any plugin (and I don't use Nagios), but it shouldn't be too hard to roll your own (as you mentioned your experience with Nagios and custom checks)...

The notify system is quite easy and called from the terminal (or script) via `notify-send "summary" "body"`.

If you can the check of your hosts via a script, combining the notify and Nagios check shouldn't be too difficult.

That script could then be put into an indicator if you want and there are plenty of [examples](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available); in particular I've written `indicator-fortune` which simply displays a fortune in the notify-osd and will give you a good start in getting an indicator with notify.